# Product reviews not showing up on product review page

Tags: php, xml, magento

Product review page doesn't show product reviews + review form. It is only happening in my custom theme. If I change theme to Magento's default theme then product reviews + review form are visible on product review page.

Actually, the changes made in custom theme are done by another coder. So, I have no idea why this is happening.

Can anyone guide me to the files in which I should be looking for the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

product/view.phtml was missing:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

In product page details appears to you the link "Rate this product"?

If not displayed enter the following code in the file view.phtml which is in app / design / frontend / base / default / template / catalog / product

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
```

In my case, I would like to display the comments and review form still in the product detail page, without leaving the page, hen added the following code in the same file view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_review') ?>
```

You can also try adding the above code in view.phtml which is in app / design / frontend / base / default / template / review